# Mixing Haskell and C++

Tags: c++, haskell, ffi

If you had the possibility of having an application that would use both Haskell and C++.
What layers would you let Haskell-managed and what layers would you let C++-managed ?

Has any one ever done such an association, (surely) ?

(the Haskell site tells it's really easy because Haskell has a mode where it can be compiled in C by gcc)

At first I think I would keep all I/O operations in the C++ layers. As well as GUI management.

It is pretty vague a question, but as I am planning to learn Haskell, I was thinking about delegating some work to Haskell-code (I learn in actually coding), and I want to choose some part where I will see Haskell benefits.

Comment: It would be useful to describe what type of application you plan to build.

Comment: I have several projects. Each really different. What's important is what Haskell is good at, better than C++ at, and then try to code Haskell in such part so as to learn Haskell and to judge by myself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The benefit of Haskell is the powerful abstractions it allows you to use. You're not thinking in terms of ones and zeros and addresses and registers but computations and type properties and continuations.

The benefit of C++ is how tightly you can optimize it when necessary. You aren't thinking about high-minded monads, arrows, partial application, and composing pure functions: with C++, you can get right down to the bare metal!

There's tension between these two statements. In his paper [“Structured Programming with `go to` statements,”](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.103.6084) Donald Knuth wrote

> I have felt for a long time that a talent for programming consists largely of the ability to switch readily from microscopic to macroscopic views of things, *i.e.*, to change levels of abstraction fluently.

Knowing how to use Haskell and C++ but also how and when to *combine* them well will knock down all sorts of problems.

The last big project I wrote that used [FFI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction) involved using an in-house radar modeling library written in C. Reimplementing it would have been silly, and expressing the high-level logic of the rest of the application would have been a pain. I kept the “brains” of it in Haskell and called the C library when I needed it.

You're wanting to do this as an exercise, so I'd recommend the same approach: write the smarts in Haskell. Shackling Haskell as a slave to C++ will probably end up frustrating you or making you feel as though you wasted your time. Use each language where its strengths lie.

Comment: Thanx for inverting my position. Haskell should call C++. I will try this. But it also means then that the core of the application is Haskell driven. So you are meaning that the object, functionnal, and template programming avaiable in C++ is less flexible than the possibilities offered by Haskel? Haskel will tightly stick to the fundamentals flows and logics of the application I may build ? is that what you mean?

Comment: And thanx for Knuth's article, (fundamentals never hurt). Though it's not freely available through ACM ( well I have no account there), it can be download at CiteSeerx

Comment: This is really quite wrong. You can optimize C++ tightly when necessary- but you absolutely can think in terms of lists, garbage collection and pattern matching in C++. You're thinking of C.

Comment: @DeadMG that's what I am trying to understand. At what extent do they feel like the C++ high-level abstractions may be less competitive compared to Haskell high-level abstraction. But something in what have read gives me a clue: the shortness of code. It's is claimed that Functionnal code may be shorter by a factor of 2 to 10. Even more with Erlang language.

Comment: C++ is not noted for being particularly concise, it's true. But then, if you want to use Haskell/C++, you will have to deal with all the interop, which isn't exactly going to be trivial between two pretty unrelated languages. As for 2 to 10? I don't think it'll be THAT much.

Comment: @DeadMG I chose poor examples and only hinted at the elegance dimension, but please don't take me as bashing C++. The language has its definite strengths.

Comment: @Stephane The language we use [shapes our thinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity). The imperative roots of C++ tend to bog down a program's expression in the how, and [patterns are signs of weakness in programming languages.](http://blog.plover.com/prog/design-patterns.html) Moving in the declarative direction, the scaffolding disappears, leaving the essence, which is easy to reason about. Of course, it's still possible to write beautiful programs in C++ and ugly ones in Haskell, but learning multiple paradigms will make you a better programmer.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: If you want to learn Haskell, then go learn Haskell, then come back and ask the question. There's a difference between "How can I learn Haskell?" and "How can I interop Haskell and C++?". @gbacon: I didn't intend to suggest that you were bashing C++, merely that I felt that you gave an unfair view of it's high-level facilities, and I certainly agree that multiple paradigm is stronger.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm gonna learn Haskell interoping with C++. For example, I can't imagine working with multiple audio samples arrays @ 44,100Hz with Haskell as easy as in C++. But dealing with high-level abstract musical structures... well I wanted to know where I can experiment Haskell with its strength and test them. I think it's worth trying there.

Comment: @gbacon I will need some more time with the second link as I am a fellow follower of the Design Patterns in C++ :-) I need some time to swallow :-)))

Comment: @Stephane Include a link in a comment as an inline Markdown link, *i.e.*, **[** *link-text* **](** *link-url* **)**

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I see things:

- Functional languages excel at *transforming things*. Whenever you write programs which take an input and map/filter/reduce it, use functional constructs. Wonderful real world examples where Haskell should excel are given by web applications (you basically transform things stored in a database to web pages).
- Procedural languages (OOP languages *are* procedural) excel at side effects and communication between objects. They are cumbersome to use to transform data, but whenever you want to do system programming or (bidirectional) interaction with humans (user interfaces of any kind, including client-side web programming), they do the job cleanly.
- However, some may argue that user interfaces should have a functional description, I answer that well established frameworks are easy enough to use with OOP languages that one should use them this way. After all, it is natural to think of UI components in terms of objects and communication between objects.
- IO is only a tool: whenever you transform input to output, Haskell (or whatever FP language) should do the IO. Whenever you speak to a human, C++ (or whatever OOP language) should do the IO.
- Don't care about speed. When you use Haskell for the right job, it's efficient. When you use C++ or Python for the right job, it's efficient.

Therefore, let's say I'm fluent in Haskell, C, C++ and Python, here's how I write applications:

- If my application's main role is to transform data, I write it in Haskell, with possibly some low-level parts written in C (which may, in turn, call some high-tech low level parts written in C++, but I'd stick with C as an interface for portability reasons).
- If my application's main role is to interact with a user, I write it in Python (PyQt for instance), and let Python call performance-critical routines written in C++ (boost::python is pretty good as a binding generator). I may also have to call subroutines which transform or fetch data, which will be written in Haskell.
- If I have to write a part of an application in Haskell, I segregate it into a C-callable API.
- Sometimes, a Haskell application which reads things on stdin and write back on stdout is useful as a submodule (that you call with fork/exec, or whatever on your platform). Sometimes, a shell script is the right wrapper for such applications.

Comment: with weeks going by, I have fallen back on F# rather than Haskell. Namely for less complexness, and .Net compatibility.  I'll come back to Haskell when I am well at ease with F#. And I take your opinions about Functionnal programming as well for Haskell than for F#.

Comment: still thinking about your post. When you mention Functionnal Programming good for transforming, e.g. web apps: given a database, and a graphical theme -> web site. But I don't have heard about Haskell web sites programming yet, could you enlight me about that ?

Comment: @Stephane: It is mainly because most web programmers often don't have intense knowledge of computer science... Web programming has mainly been trusted by php (which is bad). You can use F# with ASP.Net (and I suspect it is the main reason for introducing F# in the first place), which is good. Look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Practical_web_programming_in_Haskell to wit the beauty and simplicity of doing web programming in functional languages.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is more a story than a comprehensive answer, but I used a mix of Haskell, Python and C++ for my dissertation in computational linguistics, as well as several C and Java tools that I didn't write. I found it simplest to run everything as a separate process, using Python as glue code to start the Haskell, C++ and Java programs.

The C++ was a fairly simple, tight loop that counted feature occurrences. Basically all it did was math and simple I/O. I actually controlled options by having the Python glue code write out a header full of `#define`s and recompiling. Kind of hacky, but it worked.

The Haskell was all the intermediate processing: taking the complex output from the various C and Java parsers that I used, filtering extraneous data, and transforming it the simple format the C++ code expected. Then I took the C++ output and transformed it into LaTeX markup (among other formats).

This is an area that you would expect Python to be strong, but I found that Haskell makes manipulation of complex structures easier; Python is probably better for simple line-to-line transformations, but I was slicing and dicing parse trees and I found that I forgot the input and output types when I wrote code in Python.

Since I was using Haskell a lot like a more-structured scripting language, I ended up writing a few file I/O utilities, but beyond that, the built in libraries for tree and list manipulation sufficed.

In summary, if you have a problem like mine, I would suggest C++ for the memory-constrained, speed-critical part, Haskell for the high-level transformations, and Python to run it all.

Comment: My program was a batch operation, with no GUI, so C++ and Haskell didn't talk to each other at all, except through files. I started them both using Python's subprocess.Popen so I could maximise use of the cores on my machine. So Python didn't really talk to the others either. BUT I found I didn't need much C++ either--only the central, most memory-hogging algorithm. If you need a lot of C++, or you need close co-operation between the pieces of your program, then my method may not work well.

Comment: *transformation* is the key word. Functional languages are the right tool if and only if you're transforming things.

Answer (score 5):

I have never mixed both languages but your approach feels a little upside down to me.
Haskell is more apt at high-level operations while C++ can be optimized and can be most beneficial for tight loops and other performance critical code.

One of the largest benefits of Haskell is the encapsulation of IO into monads. As long as this IO isn't time critical I don't see any reason to do it in C++.

For the GUI part you are probably right. There is a plethora of Haskell GUI libraries but C++ has powerful tools such as QtCreator which simplify the tedious tasks a lot.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem upside down to you. You are clearly saying: Use Haskell for everything. Except maybe GUI and time critical operations. That's the reason you don't understand I may mix the two languages. There's a little reason that keep me in the C++ island ( though I have not learnt Haskell enough to do any comparisons), with C++ I still feel what's happening behind, speaking about hardware operation I mean.

Comment: I don't think pmr is saying that. You asked what the relative strengths are - and pmr's answer is pretty accurate. If you feel more comfortable with an imperative style, that's fine. But it's your own feeling, not a comparison of what the languages are good at, which is what you originally asked for.

Comment: Yeah it's a feeling, I completely agree with that, all the more so as I don't know Haskell enough. (i made pmr +1)